# JDBC OCI Query Notification Sample

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface

I am looking for a sample program using the OCI JDBC driver (Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.1.0) trying the [query notification feature](https://students.kiv.zcu.cz/doc/oracle/appdev.112/e10646/oci10new.htm) provided by Oracle 11gr2. Since the oracle link shows a c/c++ example it would be great if someone has already tried out and can share a working sample using the oci jdbc driver.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the examples in the JDBC developer's guide:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/dbmgmnt.htm#CHDEJECF

(Btw: I don't think OCI is required for this, with the 11.x drivers, this should work with the thin driver as well)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. The strange fact is that the oci-jdbc driver does not support the database change notification feature. Have you encountered this?

Comment: @Amit: sorry, I have never used the OCI driver.